# Convert GMSPanoramaView to UIImage?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, google-street-view, gmsmapview

For my application, I need to get a Google Street View image from gps coordinates. I know how to get a full screen GMSPanoramaView from coordinates, but I ultimately need it to be a UIImage.

```
        let panoView = GMSPanoramaView(frame: .zero)
        self.view = panoView
        panoView.moveNearCoordinate(location.coordinate)
        panoView.setAllGesturesEnabled(false)

        // can this be converted to a UIImage?
        var streetViewImage: UIImage?
        streetViewImage = panoView
```

I'm seeing that other people have presented the GMSPanoramaView in a subview - is this a better option? Or are there any other ways to get **static UIImages** from Google Street View?

Comment: GMSPanoramaView is subclass of UIView so you can convert view to image by UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions. Try below answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public extension GMSPanoramaView {

    @objc public func toImage() -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, false, UIScreen.main.scale)
        drawHierarchy(in: self.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }
}
```

The above code will take a screenshot of your view. To have the right data loaded from the network (and not get a black screenshot) you will need to implement GMSPanoramaViewDelegate, probably panoramaView:didMoveToPanorama: will be called when the network request is completed and the image is visible. By then you can call `toImage()` and store your image.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/protocol_g_m_s_panorama_view_delegate-p

Comment: Like this: let streetViewImage = panoView.toImage() ? I'm getting "Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" at the line "let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!"

Comment: I missed this before. You're initializing the view frame to .zero, this is why there is no visible area to take a screenshot from. Try using some frame with values

Comment: No errors, but I'm getting a grey image with the loading indicator circle in the centre and the Google logo in the bottom left corner. Is it capturing the image before it's finished loading?

Comment: I think the issue might be with the view frame? Even when I try to present the panoView in a smaller GMSPanoramaView in the main view, I get a black image that is continuously loading. Right now I have: let panoView = GMSPanoramaView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 250, height: 250))

Comment: You want to do this in a callback when the data is retrieved. Look in google api for it

Comment: Sorry @jugutier, I'm not sure what you mean. I'll have to try something else. Thanks for all your help here.

Comment: @CarrotsAndCoding sorry I was on the phone last night. Please see my updated answer above regarding delegate implementation

Comment: Does this just mean making the View Controller class a delegate and then adding panoramaView:didMoveToPanorama to the class? I'm still super new to Swift and don't completely understand delegates.

Comment: Yes, implement that delegate method and call toImage In the delegate method

Comment: I implemented the delegate and I'm still getting a grey loading image. I've confirmed that the delegate method is actually being called as well. Any ideas? Here is the stripped down code: https://repl.it/repls/FrostyUnequaledHoiho

Comment: That looks like it should work. I’ll have to run it from home to be sure.

Comment: Ya I'm totally at a loss. Please let me know if you test it!

Comment: Finally figured it out. I had to 1) add the GMSPanoramaView as a subview in my view controller, and 2) convert the subview to an image after a delay of 2-3 seconds, so that the pano view had time to load. I just need the resulting image, so I'm going to cover up the pano subview with another view. Example code here: https://repl.it/repls/FrostyUnequaledHoiho

Comment: Glad to hear that! It didn't occur to me that the view wasn't part of the current view hierarchy. This is always necessary so that the rendering happens. If you don't want it in your view hierarchy you can hide it as you very well said OR you can hold a dummy view controller in some variable and add the panoview to it. The timing for the image to load is also essential. This can happen in one of the delegate methods or by setting a timer... If you set a timer by hand it may depend on the network connection and may not work on slower networks.

Comment: @CarrotsAndCoding could you please mark the answer as selected if it met your needs? that way the question it can help other people that find this later :) happy new year!